# How to say I want to leave colloquially?

Tags: vocabulary, conversation

How to say I want to leave or I want to go home colloquially in the case of we are visiting someone's place?

Let's say I'm visiting my auntie, then when it's the time for me to leave, what should I say to her?

Is it ok to say "姑姑，我先走啊" ?

But I feel 先走 sounds awkward. Is there better colloquial alternative words?

Answer (score 5):

我先走了 is a perfect way to say.
you can also say,我得(děi)走了; 我要走了;我得(děi)回家了;我还有点事,先走了; 好了,我得(děi)走了;不早了,我先走了;行,我先回去了;

Answer (score 2):

You've got it dude **先走** is a great way to express that it's time for you to leave.

If you feel like it's too much you can just say **我走了** without the whole pomp and circumstance.

edit: if you feel it's too *mean* then you can explain why you've gotta go (我走了，已经很晚了) - but shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I'm visiting my auntie, then when it's the time for me to leave, what should I say to her?

If at night or afternoon , I will say "天不早了, 我该走了" which it's late that I should leave. It is very normal in north China , especially in countryside.

Or "我有点事, 我该走了." means "I have something to do, and I should leave"